# Consulta Sql Server Lenta No order by

Tags: sql, sql-server

Boa Noite

Faço uma pesquisa slq server 2019 para receber o ultimo campo registrado de 3 tabelas distintas.

Quando faço a pesquisa sem o order by ela fica muito rapida,  mas quando uso o order by para pegar ordernar os registros ela fica lenta e demora demais para me retornar os dados.

```
SELECT top 1 
       a.Percentual,  
       b.Percentual, 
       a.DataHora, 
       b.DataHora, 
       c.Percentual,
       b.DataHora
FROM Nivel_A1_Reservatorio_ETA As a 
cross join Nivel_A1_Reservatorio_Cabral AS b 
cross join Nivel_A1_Reservatorio_Alto_Samambaia as c 
order by a.DataHora desc, 
b.DataHora desc,
c.DataHora desc
```

Obs: Precisa ser order by porque preciso pegar o ultimo registro exato de cada uma das 3 tabelas

Comment: Brother ja tentou incluir um limit? Tive esse problema em algumas querys por conta do tamanho da fila.

Comment: Provavelmente terá que [criar índices](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) para otimizar a performance da consulta. Sem mais informações sobre o esquema das tabelas envolvidas na consulta e o [plano de execução da consulta](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/relational-databases/performance/execution-plans?view=sql-server-ver16) não tem como melhor o orientar.

Comment: Não seria o caso de UNION ?

Comment: @Motta  fiz conforme sql abaixo mas os dados não vem na sequência das tabelas                                                                                                             
                SELECT * FROM
 (
  SELECT  TOP 1
a.Percentual,a.DataHora FROM Nivel_A1_Reservatorio_ETA as a
ORDER BY a.Datahora DESC
 
  union SELECT  top 1  b.Percentual,b.DataHora FROM Nivel_A2_Reservatorio_ETA  as b
 order by b.Datahora DESC


   union SELECT  top 1  c.valor,c.DataHora FROM Vazao_A1_Booster_Central  as c
 order by c.Datahora DESC
 
 ) AS tb

Comment: tente com max select * from ETA t1 where t1.data = (select max(t2,data) from ETA t2) union select * from Cabral t1 where t1.data = (select max(t2,data) from Cabral t2) union select * from Alto t1 where t1.data = (select max(t2,data) from Alto t2)

Comment: o cross join multiplica todas as linhas de uma tabela com as das outras então está tendo um disperdício de processamento muito grande... vc pode usar sub-selects ou UNION pra pegar somente o ultimo de cada tabela e depois juntar em colunas no select superior, ou utilizar funções de rank pra isso

Answer (score 0):

Exemplo utilizando UNION, assim os dados ainda ficam em linhas o que é melhor pra trabalhar dentro da aplicação... se quiser pode utilizar um PIVOT, mas depende da sua necessidade.

```
SELECT top 1 
'ETA' as id,
a.Percentual,  
a.DataHora
FROM Nivel_A1_Reservatorio_ETA As a order by a.DataHora desc

UNION 

Select TOP 1
'CABRAL',
b.Percentual,
b.DataHora
FROM Nivel_A1_Reservatorio_Cabral AS b ORDER BY b.DataHora desc

UNION 

Select TOP 1
'ALTO SAMAMBAIA',
c.Percentual,
c.DataHora
FROM Nivel_A1_Reservatorio_Alto_Samambaia AS c ORDER BY c.DataHora desc
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM
 (
 SELECT top 1 
'1' as id,
a.Percentual,  
a.DataHora
FROM Nivel_A1_Reservatorio_ETA As a order by a.DataHora desc

UNION 

Select TOP 1
'2',
b.Valor,
b.DataHora
FROM Nivel_A1_Reservatorio_Cabral AS b ORDER BY b.DataHora desc

UNION 

Select TOP 1
'3',
c.Percentual,
c.DataHora
FROM Nivel_A1_Reservatorio_Alto_Samambaia AS c ORDER BY c.DataHora desc

 
 ) AS tb

Comment: resolveu aqui valeu

Answer (score 0):

Fiz Assim, e ordenei pelo id usando numeração, me ajudou bastante obrigado
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT top 1
'1' as id,
a.Percentual,
a.DataHora
FROM Nivel_A1_Reservatorio_ETA As a order by a.DataHora desc

UNION

Select TOP 1
'2',
b.Valor,
b.DataHora
FROM Nivel_A1_Reservatorio_Cabral AS b ORDER BY b.DataHora desc

UNION

Select TOP 1
'3',
c.Percentual,
c.DataHora
FROM Nivel_A1_Reservatorio_Alto_Samambaia AS c ORDER BY c.DataHora desc

```
) AS tb
```